# NStoolbar in NSWindow position is change

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I am adding toolbar in NSwindow. When the window is opened and close the window again when I open the window, the window position is changed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it getting changed after relaunching the app?

Comment: Yes but not relaunching the app. It is changed in close.

Comment: How do you add the toolbar? How do you open the window? Is `frameAutosaveName` set?